# I am trying to take multiple images from an html form into my Flask app.py function and then save those images to a dynamically created file path

Tags: database, image, flask, directory, permissions

This is my html page:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Add Venue
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <h2>Add Venue</h2>
    <p>List a venue for hire here!</p>

    <form action="/add_venue" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mb-3 form-container">
            <label class="form-label"><strong>Name</strong></label>
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control mx-auto w-auto form-field" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Address</strong></label>
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto form-field" type="text" name="address">

            <label class="form-label"><strong>City</strong></label>
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto form-field" type="text" name="city">

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Country</strong></label>
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto form-field" type="text" name="country">

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Post Code</strong></label>
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto form-field" type="integer" name="post_code">

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Select Venue amenities</strong></label>
            <label for="#">
                <input  type="radio" id="#" name="#" value="#">
                #
            </label>

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Venue Description</strong></label>
            <textarea class="form-control form-field f-description" id="description" name="description" rows="5" cols="100" placeholder="Event Description (max 300 characters)" maxlength="300"></textarea>

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Add upto 10 images</strong></label>
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto form-field" type="file" name="images" multiple accept="image/*" max="10">

            <label class="form-label"><strong>Select the categories this venue can be used for</strong></label>
            <select id="categories" name="categories" class="form-select form-field">
                <option value=""></option>
          
                <option value="#">#</option>
     
            </select>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Venue</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my app.py flask app config with the add_venue function:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, get_flashed_messages
from flask_session import Session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from functions import login_required, request_error, allowed_image_files
from datetime import datetime


# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.app_context().push()


#Link SQL data base to the current app.py file
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = r'sqlite:///C:/Programming/Python/Python/Programs/CS50_FP/events/database/events.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Import models after configuration of db and app instance
from models import User, Events, Venues

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Define image upload standard directory
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static\\images'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



# ensure client gets latest data in responses
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Ensure responses aren't cached"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

#ADD VENUE
@app.route("/add_venue", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add_venue():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        address = request.form.get("address")
        city = request.form.get("city")
        country = request.form.get("country")
        post_code = request.form.get("post_code")
        amenities = request.form.get("amenities")
        categories = request.form.get("amenities")
        images = request.files.getlist("images")
        description = request.form.get("description")

        image_urls = []
        date_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d--%H_%M_%S")

        for image in images:
            if image and allowed_image_files(image.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(image.filename)

                file_path_save = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
                                            f'venues\\{country}\\{city}\\{name}\\user_id_{session["user_id"]}\\', 
                                            date_time)
                                            
                
                file_path_db = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 
                                            f'venues\\{country}\\{city}\\{name}\\user_id_{session["user_id"]}\\',
                                            date_time, 
                                            filename)
                                            
                os.makedirs(file_path_save, exist_ok=True)
                image.save(file_path_save)
                image_urls.append(file_path_db)


        new_venue = Venues(
            name=name, 
            address=address, 
            city=city,
            country=country,
            post_code=post_code,
            amenities=amenities,
            categories=categories,
            images=', '.join(image_urls),# Converts image url list into a string 
            description=description,
            owner_id=session["user_id"]
        )

        
        db.session.add(new_venue)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect("/venues")
        
    else:
        return render_template("venues/add_venue.html")
```

I know there is still logic missing in the add_venue function e.g. dealing with categories and amenities etc. For now, I am just trying to deal with the image handling side of it. I want to save the actual image into a static dynamically created directory and then save the path to that image in the db.

When this function runs though it creates the directories, but then when it tries to save the actual image, I get this permission denied error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'static\images\venues\wefwefwe\efwefwef\f434f3\user_id_1\2024_01_21--15_37_09'
> 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jan/2024 15:37:09] "POST /add_venue HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Ignore the naming of the file path in the error. I am just typing in randomness for testing. I have confirmed I have permissions on the folder structures up to the point where the new directories get created e.g. "static/images..."